# Polymer1.0 validation of two input[type=date]

Tags: javascript, forms, polymer-1.0

I'm starting to use Polymer and can't find answers to many questions.

I have two inputs

```
<paper-input id="startDate" type="date" 
    error-message="The end date is before the start date"></paper-input>
<paper-input id="endDate" type="date"></paper-input>
```

When both are empty or only one is filled, the form is valid. If both are filled there is a validation needed that the `endDate` is greater or equal to the `startDate`.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting started, then please go through developer guide where you can find answers for most of your questions.

In your case, you need to declare properties with values of the paper-input and observe for its changes. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#change-callbacks. In that observer you can write you logic and set any (or both) fields as invalid.

```
<dom-module id="my-form">
<template>
<paper-input id="startDate" type="date" value="{{startDate}}" error-message="The end date is before the start date"></paper-input>
<paper-input id="endDate" type="date" value="{{endDate}}"></paper-input>
</template>
<script>
(function() {
'use strict';

Polymer({
  is: 'my-form',

  properties: {
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
  },
  observers: ['_dateChange(startDate, endDate)'],
  _dateChange: function(startDate, endDate) {
     if(/*logic goes here*/) {
       this.$.startDate.invalid = true;
     } else {
       this.$.startDate.invalid = false;
     }
  }      
});
})();
</script>
</dom-module>
```